# Using the Freebase search api mql_output parameter to obtain linked data

Tags: freebase, mql

I am trying to use the freebase search API to obtain the parties of specific politicians as well as general biographical data (using php). I know that the search api passes the id of each search result found to an MQL query specified by the mql_output parameter.

Here is the MQL query I have at the moment which I use for the mql_ouput parameter

{
   "name":null,
   "/people/person/date_of_birth":null,
   "/people/person/gender":null,
   "/wikipedia/topic/en_id":null,
   "id":null,
   "/government/politician/party":[
      {
          party : null
      }
   ]
}

and this is the resultant query url

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?Barrack%20Obama&filter=%28all%20type%3Apolitician%29&mql_output=%7B%22name%22%3Anull%2C%22%5C%2Fpeople%5C%2Fperson%5C%2Fdate_of_birth%22%3Anull%2C%22%5C%2Fpeople%5C%2Fperson%5C%2Fgender%22%3Anull%2C%22%5C%2Fwikipedia%5C%2Ftopic%5C%2Fen_id%22%3Anull%2C%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22%5C%2Fgovernment%5C%2Fpolitician%5C%2Fparty%22%3A%5B%7B%7D%5D%7D&key=AIzaSyDdJ_9L6mcWXinx5Lehku2TULmJhOMESew&indent=true

Thanks for your help, sorry that it's quite  basic question,

Mark

---

**Answer**

Could not self answer due to not enough forum rep.

I just realised what I needed to do after going over some more examples. To have the database retrieve the party information I needed to use the following query.

{
   "name":null,
   "/people/person/date_of_birth":null,
   "/people/person/gender":null,
   "/wikipedia/topic/en_id":null,
   "id":null,
   "/government/politician/party":{
   "party" : null
   }
}

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realised what I needed to do after going over some more examples. To have the database retrieve the party information I needed to use the following query.

{ "name":null, "/people/person/date_of_birth":null, "/people/person/gender":null, "/wikipedia/topic/en_id":null, "id":null, "/government/politician/party":{ "party" : null } }

Mark